# Span of Hilbert base

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{e_j\}$ be an (infinite) Hilbert base of a Hilbert space $H$. Is the subspace $U=span_{\mathbb{C}}\{e_j|j\ge 0\}$ again a Hilbert Space?

Thanks

Comment: (Huge) hint: Is it complete? Why or why not?

Comment: I think it is, because any series need to converge. We only look at finite sums.

Comment: I will expand upon my comment in an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

(Huge) hint: Is it complete? Why or why not? (Even bigger hint below.)

> Consider the sequence $(x_n)\subseteq U$ such that $x_n = \sum_{m=0}^n \frac{1}{2^m} e_m.$

Follow-up:

> Let $E$ be a collection of basis vectors. Can you come up with a criterion on $E$ such that the span of $E$ is complete?

Comment: The sequence does not converge in $U$ and I could take the closure of the span of the base vectors.